# How to send a tmux configuration command externally (from bash)

Tags: tmux

In tmux, how can I set the configuration command `setw synchronize-panes off` externally (from bash).

I tried, `tmux send-keys -t 1 setw synchronize-panes off enter`, but it didn't work (it sends the command to the shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just prepend the command with `tmux`.

```
tmux setw synchronize-panes off
```

send keys is a way for tmux to run bash commands (so I could set a particular command to run in a particular pane when I do something in tmux using `send-keys`). It is not a way to interact with tmux configs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set-option` to specify the configuration you want too since `set` is an [alias](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux#:%7E:text=normal%20mode%20without.-,Options,-The%20appearance%20and).

`tmux set-option -t [TARGET PANE] option value`

*Note: target pane can mean target-session or target-window*

```
kyrlon@pc1:~$ tmux set-option -t 1 synchronize-panes off
```